# How to check if rich:component returns null

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I have a `ui:composition` called pageContent.xhtml that is included in another `ui:composition` and a `rich:popupPanel` (two different pages).

pageContent.xhtml contains an `a4j:commandButton`. In the `oncomplete` method of the button I would like to execute javascript only if the pageContent.xhtml is shown on `rich:popupPanel`. So I would like to check in pageContent.xhtml if the `rich:popupPanel` is available.

The RichFaces [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/nightly_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Functions.html) describes that `rich:component` returns `null`, if the specified component identifier is not found.

For testing reasons, I execute the following JS in the `oncomplete` method of the `a4j:commandButton`:

```
console.log('-> ' + #{rich:component('popupPanelId')});
```

If pageContent.xhtml is shown on the popup (id 'popupPanelId' is available) and I click the button I see the following result on the console:

```
-> BaseComponent, PopupPanel
```

If pageContent.xhtml is shown on the other `ui:composition` page (id 'popupPanelId' is not available) and I click the button, I got the following error message:

```
try {console.log('-> ' + );;} catch (e) {window.RichFaces.log.error('Error in me...
```

In case of `#{rich:component('popupPanelId')}` doesn't found the component nothing is returned to the resulting page instead of `null`.

How can I check if a component is available without any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EL expressions are evaluated on the server, the result is then converted to a string to be outputted on the page, null is converted to an empty string.

So you could've started with a null-check:

```
oncomplete="#{rich:component('popupPanelId') == null ? 'alert(\'not found\')' : 'alert(\'found\')'}"
```

On the other hand I assume the popupPanel is included based on some condition, a better approach would be for the @oncomplete to check the same condition. Otherwise if it is just not rendered the function will find it.